# Trying to align div to the right

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment

i am trying to align a certain div to the right. the current div is to the left.
[image]

you can see in the pic, im trying to move the name to the right and the price to the left.
tried several CSS alignments without success.
[link to section on site](https://rosaparksbar.co.il/#menu)

many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using flexbox on your site - desired change can be achieved by using [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) style:

```
.nectar_food_menu_item .item_name {
  order: 3;
}
.nectar_food_menu_item .line_spacer {
  order: 2;
}
.nectar_food_menu_item .item_price {
  order: 1;
}
```

Comment: @dormeljon I've tested this approach on your site (through dev.tools), strange that it is not working for you...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.wpb_wrapper {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also remove `float: right` on your `.inner` wrapper.